# How to specify the current directory as path in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel

I have a macro-enabled WorkBook. I need to specify the current folder in which the macro-enabled file is present as the path. I tried setting

```
path = ActiveWorkbook.Path
```

*and*

```
path = CurDir()
```

but neither of these work for me. Any idea on this?

Comment: `ActiveWorkbook.Path` is the right way to get the path. How and where are you calling this code?

Comment: Activeworkbook.path doens't exist until document is saved once does it?

Comment: If it's the file with the running macro then you want ThisWorkbook.Path

Comment: +1 Tim Williams. Yup :) hence it is important to know how and where is he calling this code from?

Comment: @Siddharth - I was going on "the current folder in which the macro enabled file is present"

Comment: @Tim Williams: Ah! I see what you mean. Nice Catch! Would recommend that you post it as an answer? Also adding to it when and why `ActiveWorkbook` and `ThisWorkbook` should be used. :)

Comment: I'm using this inside Workbook_Open() event. I tried both ActiveWorkbook and ThisWorkbook. It is not working. Instead if i hard code the path it works!

Comment: Strange. Can you post the complete `Workbook_Open()` code?

Comment: All these files go to the same folder.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I thought I had misunderstood but I was right. In this scenario, it will be `ActiveWorkbook.Path`

But the main issue was not here. The problem was with these 2 lines of code

```
strFile = Dir(strPath & "*.csv")
```

Which should have written as

```
strFile = Dir(strPath & "\*.csv")
```

and

```
With .QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & strPath & strFile, _
```

Which should have written as

```
With .QueryTables.Add(Connection:="TEXT;" & strPath & "\" & strFile, _
```

Answer (score 32):

If the path you want is the one to the workbook running the macro, and that workbook has been saved, then

`ThisWorkbook.Path`

is what you would use.