# How to loop sending emails

Tags: vba, email

I have a folder `test` that contains the following files `user1.xlsx , user2.xlsx , user3.xlsx` 
In my working spreadsheet `work.xlsx` i have corresponding addresses

```
user1.xlsx  user1name@gmail.com
user2.xlsx  user2name@yahoo.com
 ...
```

How can I send emails with the attached user1 , user2  .xlsx files to corresponding emails

```
'Email
Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)
    On Error Resume Next
    With OutMail
        .To = userVar
        .SentOnBehalfOfName = "xxxx"
        .CC = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "...
        .Body = "...
        .Attachments. .. ??
        .Send
    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing


'Close
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Have you reviewed [this MS KB](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/161088)? It details the VBA for sending an email as below:

```
Sub SendMessage(DisplayMsg As Boolean, Optional AttachmentPath)
      Dim objOutlook As Outlook.Application
      Dim objOutlookMsg As Outlook.MailItem
      Dim objOutlookRecip As Outlook.Recipient
      Dim objOutlookAttach As Outlook.Attachment

      ' Create the Outlook session.
      Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")

      ' Create the message.
      Set objOutlookMsg  = objOutlook.CreateItem(olMailItem)

      With objOutlookMsg
          ' Add the To recipient(s) to the message.
          Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add("Nancy Davolio")
          objOutlookRecip.Type = olTo

          ' Add the CC recipient(s) to the message.
          Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add("Michael Suyama")
          objOutlookRecip.Type = olCC

         ' Add the BCC recipient(s) to the message.
          Set objOutlookRecip = .Recipients.Add("Andrew Fuller")
          objOutlookRecip.Type = olBCC

         ' Set the Subject, Body, and Importance of the message.
         .Subject = "This is an Automation test with Microsoft Outlook"
         .Body = "This is the body of the message." &vbCrLf & vbCrLf
         .Importance = olImportanceHigh  'High importance

         ' Add attachments to the message.
         If Not IsMissing(AttachmentPath) Then
             Set objOutlookAttach = .Attachments.Add(AttachmentPath)
         End If

         ' Resolve each Recipient's name.
         For Each ObjOutlookRecip In .Recipients
             objOutlookRecip.Resolve
         Next

         ' Should we display the message before sending?
         If DisplayMsg Then
             .Display
         Else
             .Save
             .Send
         End If
      End With
      Set objOutlook = Nothing
  End Sub
```

Notice that you have to *Set* the *objOutlookAttach* using the *AttachmentPath*, which would be the same as the location of your file (hardcode or [use current directory as path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10215606/how-to-specify-current-directory-as-path-in-vba)). Your loop should be for each email address in a specified range, grab the corresponding filename (from adjacent cell), append it to the AttachmentPath variable, and then used to set the objOutlookAttach.

UPDATE: a more up-to-date, related MS article can be found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/816644) for additional reference and guidance.